# Google Drive API - JavaScript Insert File - Create native google doc

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I have been working with the JavaScript Google Drive API in order to create (insert) a new file.  It works great, except that the document it creates is not a google doc, but some kind of document that can be converted in to a google doc.

I would like an actual google doc.  I tried "convert:true", but it does not seem to convert it to a doc.

```
insertFile: function (filename, content, callback) {
  const boundary = '-------314159265358979323846';
  const delimiter = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n";
  const close_delim = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--";

  {
    var contentType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.document';
    var metadata = {
      'title': filename,
      'mimeType': 'text/html',
      'description': 'Created'
    };

    // TODO: replace this with a library - https://github.com/beatgammit/base64-js/blob/master/lib/b64.js
    var base64Data = window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(content)));
    var multipartRequestBody =
        delimiter +
        'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' +
        JSON.stringify(metadata) +
        delimiter +
        'Content-Type: ' + contentType + '\r\n' +
        'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n' +
        '\r\n' +
        base64Data +
        close_delim;

    var request = gapi.client.request({
      'path': '/upload/drive/v2/files',
      'method': 'POST',
      'params': {'uploadType': 'multipart', 'convert': true },
      'headers': {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary="' + boundary + '"'
      },
      'body': multipartRequestBody
    });
    if (!callback) {
      callback = function (file) {
        console.log(file)
      };
    }
    request.execute(callback);
  }
}
```

After I insert the file, when I go to the link I get:

[image: Image of google drive screen]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I found your error. Try migrating to `v3`, according to [v3 migration](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration#other_changes):

> **Other changes**
>
> Imports to Google Docs formats are now requested by setting the appropriate target mimeType in the resource body, rather than specifying ?convert=true.
>
> Import operations will return a 400 error if the format is not supported.

And here is the link for the [list of supported mimeType](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/mime-types).